# Doxygen: Partial Classes not supported?

Tags: c#, doxygen, partial-classes

I'm attempting to use Doxygen to document my web project, which contains mostly C# user controls, each of which is a partial class that inherits from UserControl.

Example

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Dashboard_Ctrls_Dashboard : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

Within these partial classes I have a ton of methods with triple slash commenting, but with Doxygen it doesn't even seem to realize that this partial class exists, and so ignores everything in it.

Has anyone else seen this sort of behavior, and hopefully have a solution?

Many thanks.

EDIT
Here is how I comment code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Shows a message indicating that a search cannot currently be performed.
/// </summary>
```

And Here is my Doxygen config

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "Front End"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 3.6
PROJECT_BRIEF          = 
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = C:/Users/Jeff/Desktop/docTest3.6
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 8
ALIASES                = 
TCL_SUBST              = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = 
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
SYMBOL_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_DIRECTORIES       = NO
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 
CITE_BIB_FILES         = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = "C:/TFS/TIM Project/Main/3.6"
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.d \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.idl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.cs \
                         *.php \
                         *.php3 \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_ALIGN_MEMBERS     = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
USE_INLINE_TREES       = NO
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = 
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
LATEX_FOOTER           = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_SCHEMA             = 
XML_DTD                = 
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration::additions related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = NO
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               = 
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

Example of class that is not documented

```
[Serializable]
public partial class DesktopModules_Dashboard_Ctrls_Dashboard : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shows a message indicating that a search cannot currently be performed.
    /// </summary>
    private void DisplaySqlExceptionError(Exception ex)
    {
        resetErrors();
        new TrapError(ex, "Dashboard SQL Timeout/Error", true);
        spanSearchError.InnerHtml += errorPath + ltrTryAgainLater.Text;
        spanSearchError.Visible = true;
        spanSearchCount.Visible = false;
        HideSearchResults();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to go deeper then that. I took out the partial declaration and the inheritance and it STILL doesn't work. It can't be the serializable keyword because my other classes that are working have that as well.

Comment: Does it work if you set `EXTRACT_ALL` to `YES` in the configuration file or if you add a `\file` command to document the file your class is in? It would be helpful to see a minimal example of how you are actually documenting your classes.

Comment: I'm using the Doxygen Gui frontend + app, and I do indeed have extract all selected. As for how I'm commenting, I'm using triple slashes. I edited the post with an example.

Comment: Can you post a short example of your documentation plus your source code (it matters where your documentation is relative to the class you are documenting)? Try making a small file with one class plus documentation for which doxygen does not generate the documentation you expected it to.

Comment: Also, why is `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA` set to `YES` in your configuration file? Does this need to be the case if you are documenting C#?

Comment: Yea, on the non-expert tab it is for java/c#, but in the expert tab it just labels it as java. Also, I added an example of a class that is not working.

Comment: Ok. It seems that you document a class member but not the class itself. Try adding some documentation for `DesktopModules_Dashboard_Ctrls_Dashboard` and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: My other classes don't have comments and they work, but I tried anyways, no luck unfortunately.

Comment: I found out this is working with other partial classes, but not for this one. I am not really seeing a difference in the class itself, it is serializable but other classes in the same cs are also serializable and work, and it inherits from usercontrol, which other do as well and they work.

Comment: Start by looking in the generated XML documentation file to see if the compiler is failing to generate the documentation or if Doxygen is failing to include it.

Comment: @David: doxygen works on source code, not the comment extraction done by the C# compiler.

Answer (score 4):

The function you're attempting to document is `private`, so you'll also need to enable the following configuration options:

```
EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES
```

From the documentation for EXTRACT_ALL:

```
# If the EXTRACT_ALL tag is set to YES doxygen will assume all entities in
# documentation are documented, even if no documentation was available.
# Private class members and static file members will be hidden unless
# the EXTRACT_PRIVATE and EXTRACT_STATIC tags are set to YES
```

Comment: A public partial class is private? I thought it was public?

Comment: The class is declared public, but the function your attempting to extract (`DisplaySqlExceptionError` in your example) is declared private. Since the class members are private, `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` must be set to `YES` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with partial classes and not getting the documentation I wanted.  Searching led me to this issue:

My class contained the functions is declared

```
  namespace RTP.Coms {
    /// <summary>Base class for communications library</summary>
    public static partial class RTPComs {

...
   public static RTP_MESSAGE_CODE AutoDetectFixtureHardware(Boolean bShowFailMessageBox = false) {
```

For me, setting
`EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES`
did NOT help get my documentation extracted

By looking at the source file html page - I can see that it recognized the leading comments - and "hid" them -but the documentation is not displayed anywhere

Eventually I was able to explore and enable the following flags in the doxygen configuration file that yielded success for me.

```
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
RECURSIVE              = YES
```

I write this as a hint to others that may be new to Doxygen, and need to examine and configure the other EXTRACT* settings.  In my case, it was a combination of settings that got my partial class documentation extracted successfuly.

PS.
doxygen -v reports

```
1.8.18 (a1feee17d60154f5cca19d1a7fe7a69f77ee026d*)
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Please show a small complete example as well as the setting in the doxygen settings file that differs from the default settings so it is possible to reproduce the problem.